# RDS 2016 minimum services

Tags: azure, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2016, rds, remote-desktop-gateway

I wish to put in place a HA 2016 RDS service in azure that will provide remote desktop services to users connected via a VPN, there are multiple articles and deployment templates that deploy the web and gateway servers, are these needed or could I just put in place.

3 session hosts
2 connection brokers (both on domain controllers connected to azure SQL)
2 License servers(possibly also on the domain controllers)
My goal is to provide a HA RDS for internal users with minimum servers possible
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to deploy a scalable high available Desktop-as-a-Service solution in Azure, you can [start just with 4 VMs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/Desktop-hosting-logical-architecture) and scale as you grow.

Remote Desktop Services has two standard architectures:

- Basic deployment – This contains the minimum number of servers to
  create a fully effective RDS environment
- Highly available deployment – This contains all necessary components
  to have the highest guaranteed uptime for your RDS environment

**Highly available deployment**
[image]

More information about this, please refer to this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloudbp/2016/11/15/new-rds-capabilities-in-windows-server-2016-for-service-providers/).

You could use [template](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloudbp/2017/01/09/quickly-deploy-rds-2016-in-azure/) to deploy your RDS PAAS service.

If you want to use VPN to connect RDS service, you need create a [Site-to-Site VPN to Azure Virtual Network](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal).

Comment: Ok thanks but do I need the RDGW(Gateway) and the RDWeb

Comment: Yes, you need. But if you deploy it using template, you don't need deploy them alone.

Comment: @user3129787, you could check the blog and use template to deploy your RDS service. When the RDS service is created, you need deploy a site-to-site VPN.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm assuming if deploying rdweb and rdgateway then a VPN is not essential as these secure the comms via SSL over the internet, from what I can make out if you were to have a VPN then you wouldn't need rdweb or rd gateway as you can connect straight to the broker which will distribute the in coming connections?

Comment: If you deploy a VPN connection, you could access your RDS service with private IP.Also, if you want to access it with Public IP, you don't need it.